# Django mptt admin category

Tags: django, object, categories, mptt

I am using the basic configuration for Django Mptt Admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mptt.admin import MPTTModelAdmin
from teklifpark.categories.models import Category

admin.site.register(Category, MPTTModelAdmin)
```

But in the admin panel I cannot view category names. I can create but while choosing the parent category in the drop down box I can only view Category Object instead of name of the category how can I fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure that you didn't added

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.title
```

in your Category class

Answer (score 0):

I saw on the #django channel a similar question to yours take a look here http://django-irc-logs.com/2011/jul/13/#52263

hope that helps

Comment: The mptt is working but the problem is when I try to add a new category in the drop down list I am viewing category object for each category instead of the category name list